# Does fulfillment changes require a new review?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

Given I have a *published* google assistant voice app with dialogflow. If I change fulfillment parameters (e. g. sent headers or URL), will this require a new review of the voice app?

If so, how can I smoothly change these parameters without breaking my app? I never really know when the review is finished, but I have to since I would need to change my deployment configuration to fit the new fulfillment properties in the right moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fulfillment changes do not require a new review. Once you deploy to your server, it is effectively live and new users will use the latest webhook. Things that do require a new review are:

- Actions on Google console changes such as a thumbnail or description ...etc.
- Changes made to the [action package](https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/define-actions) (if you are using Actions SDK).
- Changes made to Dialogflow that involve adding or removing account linking and/or involve things like adding intents or user expressions for implicit invocation purposes.

Once you pass the first review, it will frequently be faster for simple changes like these.